# Executing a TFS Build Agent outside the domain of the Build Controller

Tags: domain, team-foundation-server

I have the requirement to execute a build agent on a machine that is outside the domain of the build controller. Is this possible and if so, is any extra configuration needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, with the following conditions.

The domain that the build agent is in must trust the domain that the build controller is in

The build agent service account should be a member of the domain that the controller is in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I believe I missed an important detail in my question. The build agent needs to run on a workgroup PC rather than a 2nd domain. Is that possible?

Sorry for my mistake.